# Queue SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a dataset which has been broken down into 349 .csv files. All the files are stored in the same folder and the files have be given sequential numbers. (Recommendations-1.csv, Recommendations-2.csv, Recommendations-3.csv...)

I'm using the following command to import the files, the only thing that changes in each import statement is the file number

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/USERNAME/OneDrive/Data/EPC Register/Data Import Files/recommendations-1.csv' 
INTO TABLE`epc_reg
`FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS`

MySQL doesn't support the use of variables to change the file name. Is there a wayto run these queries sequentially as opposed to manually waiting for one import to complete, editing the query and running again? (I'm happy with creating the same query 349 times providing I can leave it to run).

Comment: Well you could write a little batch file to do the incrementing. Or just add all the files into one file and run it once

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this assuming you use bash is:

```
for filename in $(ls -l)
do
   mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/USERNAME/OneDrive/Data/EPC Register/Data Import Files/${filename}' INTO TABLEepc_reg FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS"
done
```

In this the filename from the for loop is used in the mysql command with the `${filename}`.

You will have to watch the escaping of the '"' (So some debugging might be required), but for the rest this should work.

Translation into `batch`:

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
   mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/USERNAME/OneDrive/Data/EPC Register/Data Import Files/%%f' INTO TABLEepc_reg FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS"
)
```

or even better:

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
   mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%%~ff' INTO TABLEepc_reg FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS"
)
```